# Para que serve o sscanf() e sprintf()?

Tags: c, scanf, printf

Para que serve o `sscanf()` e o `sprintf()`?

Answer (score 8):

**SSCANF**

De acordo com o livro "The ANSI C Programming Language", de Brian W. Kernighan, a função sscanf, cuja declaração é

```
int sscanf(char *s, const char *format, ...);
```

é uma função equivalente a função scanf, cuja declaração é

```
int scanf(const char *format, ...);
```

ou seja, sscanf faz o mesmo que scanf, exceto que os caracteres de entrada são recebidos da string s (veja a declaração de sscanf acima).

Exemplo:

```
int idade, ano;
char *s = (char *) malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
s = "10 50";
sscanf(s, "%d%d", &idade, &ano);
printf("-> %s\n", s);
printf("-> idade: %d, ano: %d", idade, ano);
```

no código acima a string s tem valor "10 50" e eu uso essa string como entrada na minha leitura, assim, a variável idade e ano recebem 10 e 50 respectivamente.

**SPRINTF**

De acordo com o livro "The ANSI C Programming Language", de Brian W. Kernighan, a função sscanf, cuja declaração é

```
int sprintf(char *s, const char *format, ...);
```

é uma função equivalente a função printf, cuja declaração é

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

ou seja, sprintf faz o mesmo que printf, exceto que a saída é escrita na string s com a adição do caractere nulo '\0' no final dessa string. A string s precisa ser grande o suficiente para suportar o resultado.

Exemplo:

```
int idade, ano;
char *s = (char *) malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
char *t = (char *) malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
s = "10 50";
sscanf(s, "%d%d", &idade, &ano);
printf("-> %s\n", s);
sprintf(t, "-> i: %d, a: %d", idade, ano);
printf("-> t: %s\n", t);
```

usando o mesmo exemplo anterior (com algumas adições no final), eu consigo os valores de idade e ano através de sscanf, com isso, eu escrevo a string "-> i: %d, a %d" na minha string t, sendo o primeiro %d a variavel idade, e o segundo, a variavel ano.
Se eu imprimir t, obterei "-> i: 10, a: 50".

Answer (score 7):

Quer dizer em comparação ao `scanf()` e `printf()` que são os mais comuns que as pessoas tem contato no início de aprendizado?

Esse `s` indica que a operação ocorrerá em um *buffer* de *string* previamente existente, em oposição ao console que é o normal nas funções mais comuns de entrada e saída de dados.

Todas as operações de *scan* e *printf* pegam dados de um *stream* ou mandam para um. Pode ser o console, um arquivo, ou uma *string*, ou seja, algo direto na memória.

Todos eles usam um mecanismo de formatação para ler ou dar saída de dados de tipos diversos adaptando conforme a necessidade seguindo regras estabelecidas na API dessas funções.

Documentação do [`scanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) e do [`sprintf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) junto com as demais.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).